# Nested object in Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, drop-down-menu, react-select, organization

JS noob here. I want to store a list of option for a  dropdown in an array. I want a key to be associated with every value something like this

```
 var newArray = [
      {
         key: "key",
         val:({value:"val", label:"label"}, {value:"val",label:"label"}) 
      }
    ]
```

The code above returns undefined when I try to read val. What is the solution? Thanks

Comment: Use `[]` to collect items into an array, not `()`.

Comment: So it should be `val: [...]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var newArray = [
  {
     key: "key",
     val:[{value:"val", label:"label"}, {value:"val",label:"label"}]
  }]
```

The only thing i changed were parentheses () into [], because it's the thing that declares an array. Now, if you want to read the val key, you need to do this stuff.
You have an array named "newArray". It only has 1 element (which is also the first).
Now lets get the first element of the array by `newArray[0]`. Now you have accessed the object inside the array. Now you can read the the value by `newArray[0].val`. And now you have entered a new array, which elements you can read with `newArray[0].val[0]` and `newArray[0].val[1]`